# Getting error "A non-numeric value encountered" when using parentheses with LIMIT in SELECT statements

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-order-by, union

**PLEASE SEE THE LAST EDIT ON THE BOTTOM**

---

I have the following query using MySQL in phpMyAdmin:

```
(SELECT 
  id, 
  name, 
  rank1, 
  rank2 
FROM rank_list 
LEFT JOIN names ON names.id = rank_list.name_id 
WHERE type = "typeA" 
ORDER BY rank1
LIMIT 50) 

UNION ALL

(SELECT 
  id, 
  name, 
  rank1, 
  rank2 
FROM rank_list 
LEFT JOIN names ON names.id = rank_list.name_id 
WHERE type = "typeB" 
ORDER BY rank2 
LIMIT 50)
```

- What it does is to get the top 50 ranks for `rank1` of `typeA` and merge it with top 50 ranks for `rank2` of `typeB`.
- I need to use parentheses around each sub`SELECT` because I apply a
  `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` statement to both.
- Both individually are working fine.

**PROBLEM**

I am getting the following error when applying the `UNION` to both queries:

`A non-numeric value encountered`

I really don't get it here... One thing that might cause this is that I fill `rank1` column `-1` if `type = "typeB"` (same for `rank2` and `type = "typeA"`.

Or is it something else here?

**EDIT:**

It does work when I don't apply a `LIMIT` to it

**EDIT 2**

I figured out that when doing the following (using parentheses) I also get the same error:

```
(SELECT id FROM rank_list LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Please add table definitions and 3 records of each rank

Comment: The error I might expect (without seeing the table definitions) is one of ambiguity on id in the selects - assuming you have an id column in both tables...

Comment: @P.Salmon I just edited my question. I found out that it works well when deleting the `LIMIT` statement

Answer (score 0):

try enfor the data type using a cast

```
  (SELECT 
    id, 
    name, 
    cast(rank1 AS SIGNED ), 
    cast(rank2  AS SIGNED )
  FROM rank_list 
  LEFT JOIN names ON names.id = rank_list.name_id 
  WHERE type = "typeA" 
  ORDER BY rank1
  LIMIT 50) 

  UNION ALL

  (SELECT 
    id, 
    name, 
    cast(rank1 AS SIGNED ), 
    cast(rank2  AS SIGNED )
  FROM rank_list 
  LEFT JOIN names ON names.id = rank_list.name_id 
  WHERE type = "typeB" 
  ORDER BY rank2 
  LIMIT 50)
```

Comment: This was not the reason. I found out that the query works well when deleting the `LIMIT` statment

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue

```
drop table if exists rank_list,names;
create table rank_list
(id int,name_id int,rank1 int,rank2 int,type varchar(10));
create table names
(id int, name varchar(3));

insert into rank_list values
(1,1,1,1,'typea'),(2,2,3,1,'typea'),
(2,2,1,1,'typeb');

insert into names values
(1,'aaa'),(2,'bbb');

(SELECT 
  rank_list.id, 
  name, 
  rank1, 
  rank2 
FROM rank_list 
LEFT JOIN names ON names.id = rank_list.name_id 
WHERE type = "typeA" 
ORDER BY rank1 desc
LIMIT 50) 

UNION ALL

(SELECT 
  rank_list.id, 
  name, 
  rank1, 
  rank2 
FROM rank_list 
LEFT JOIN names ON names.id = rank_list.name_id 
WHERE type = "typeB" 
ORDER BY rank2 desc
LIMIT 50);

+------+------+-------+-------+
| id   | name | rank1 | rank2 |
+------+------+-------+-------+
|    2 | bbb  |     3 |     1 |
|    1 | aaa  |     1 |     1 |
|    2 | bbb  |     1 |     1 |
+------+------+-------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note I have fully qualified id, If your model is different then without more input from you any answer or comment will be guesswork.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the table definition. My last edit in the question shows that just a basic query with parentheses and a `LIMIT` statement causes this error.

Comment: That should not be the case this code works fine in heideisql, mysqlworkbench, mysql command line and sqlfiddle so  I have to suspect phpmyadmin - can you try running from command line? AND what version of mysql are you on?

Comment: No, I don't have command line access. And I am running on MySQL 5.6.42